# Leading space to safe area , instead of saying top margin in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode-storyboard, xcode9

I am getting this new feature in Xcode 9. I am attaching the snapshot for the same. What does the safe area mean, in Xcode 9.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Safe Area**

**Apple** says is `the portion of your view that is unobscured by bars and other content`. Source: [Apple - safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)

My explanation:

`It is the guide for iPhone X for you to avoid the top notch and the bottom part for the swipe gesture that replaced the home button`

Here is a visual image for clarity:
[image: Safe Area - iPhone X]